# React Native - TabNavigator very slow compared to demo code

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am trying to do a simple tab navigation app and im using the Expo client app to view the app.

**The Problem**: the tab navigation is annoyingly slow. Compared to the demo app for the Expo client over here, by [react-navigation](https://expo.io/@react-navigation/NavigationPlayground)  and click on **Tabs Example**, its much faster in the transition.

**What I tried to do**:

**1.** I tried just making it a strict tabNavigation app without encapsulating it with a stack navigation, and that did boost up the performance just a little bit, but it was still not as swift as the demo provided by react-navigation.

**2.** Since the demo app worked faster on the Expo app, it doesn't make sense to bundle the app and deploy it through Xcode, but I did however, and it was still lagging.

I'm not quite sure what could be the issue at this point. Other questions mention that logging(console.log) causes the delay, but im not sure where that code is coming from so I did not try removing it.

Also it would be helpful if someone can confirm if React-Navigation is bridging to  native api.

Your help is appreciated.

This might help :

React native version: 0.44.0

React navigation version: 1.0.0-beta.11

heres the code im deploying

```
    import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,Text,Image} from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator,StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class Tab1 extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title:"tab1",
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Image
          source={require("./image1.png")}
          style={{width:26, height:28,tintColor: tintColor}}
        />
      ),

    };
  render(){
    return(
      <Text> tab1</Text>
    );
  }
};
class Tab2 extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title:"tab2",
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Image
          source={require("./image2.png")}
          style={{width:15, height:27,tintColor: tintColor}}
        />
      ),
    };
  render(){
    return(
      <Text>tab2 </Text>
    );
  }
};

const MainTabNavCollection = TabNavigator({
  Tb1 : {screen: Tab1 },
  Tb2 : {screen: Tab2 },
},{
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "#CC0000",
  },
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 26,
    height: 26,
  },
});

const StackNav = StackNavigator({
  one: {screen: MainTabNavCollection}
});

export default class TabNav extends React.Component{
  render() {
   return (
       <StackNav/>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Any way you can define "very slow"? Like a short video/gif comparing the two? Or timing numbers?

Comment: approximately, 0.7-0.8 second. Thats the time it takes to move from one tab to the other. try running the code if you can.

Comment: Just tried your code in both a `react-native init` generated project and an Expo generated project. Switching tabs works instantaneously for me. Perhaps try posting version and hardware information for everything.

Comment: Im testing on an iphone 5s. Im not sure if its a HW issue since the the demo app provided by react-navigation, runs alot smoother on the same phone. Do you need more HW info however?

Comment: Also post version info like `react-navigation` version, Expo version, React Native version, etc. I don't think I'll be able to track down the issue since I don't have that phone to test on but the info may help others.

Comment: I posted react-navigation and native. I have tested it on the simulator, and its faster

Comment: Hey, May be you are facing this problem because of debug mode. You will get better performance in release mode. Please update bundle and make a build for your device and see the performance. You will definitely see the difference. Hope it helps.

Comment: @vijay, I have bundled it and generated an actual app through Xcode, but performance was the same. unless you are talking about something else?